# How to use mpi4py and pytorch to train multiple model variants in parallel?

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing, mpi4py

Most use cases want to take advantage of multiple CPU cores to either do distributed training or data parallelism. I have a different use case. I'm using mpi4py to create independent "worker" processes. Each build an ANN using torch, and train on some data. There is no communication between workers during train, they are meant to be fully independent. However, by default pytorch wants to utilize all available CPU cores, and it does not respect the process boundaries of the MPI ranks. So training actually slows down when you attempt to train two networks in parallel compared to just one serially. Does anyone have experience enforcing that a single python process running torch can only utilize the single core that its MPI rank is allocated?

I have run into this problem with python 3.9 on both Mac and an HPC linux system. Thanks.

I want to train multiple separate pytorch networks in parallel. I expected training 2 networks in parallel to take the same amount of time as 1 network. Instead, training 2 networks in parallel is slower than training 1 network, because both processes attempt to use all CPU cores. This results in computation happening serially, not in parallel.